# Is it possible to use the Task Parallel Library (TPL) in C# 2.0?

Tags: c#-2.0, task-parallel-library

Currently stuck in C# 2, it would still be nice to use the parallel goodness of the TPL... is this possible?

Comment: For an alternative, why not try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550933/what-should-i-do-to-use-taskt-in-net-2-0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible. [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) requires .NET 3.5 (IIRC there was a separate download but it was a beta version) and is built in .NET 4.0.

Comment: The 3.5 version of TPL is available. It's part of the Reactive Framework download for .NET 3.5