# What should I do to use Task<T> in .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task, task-parallel-library

.NET 4.0 has the TPL which contains the nice Task class to encapsulate aynchronous programming models.  I'm working on an app that must be .NET 2.0, but I want to avoid rewriting Task.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know you said you dont want to rewrite Task, but you can actually create something fairly simple using closures, which behaves somewhat like a Task object. This is what I use:

```
    public delegate R AsyncTask<R>();

    public static AsyncTask<R> BeginTask<R>(AsyncTask<R> function)
    {
        R retv = default(R);
        bool completed = false;

        object sync = new object();

        IAsyncResult asyncResult = function.BeginInvoke(
                iAsyncResult =>
                {
                    lock (sync)
                    {
                        completed = true;
                        retv = function.EndInvoke(iAsyncResult);
                        Monitor.Pulse(sync); 
                    }
                }, null);

        return delegate
        {
            lock (sync)
            {
                if (!completed)               
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(sync); 
                }
                return retv;
            }
        };
    }
```

Its a function that calls BeginInvoke() on the delegate you pass in, and returns a function that when called blocks and waits for the result of the function passed in. You'd have to create overloads of this function for different method signatures, of course.

One way to go, you can tweak this to your needs, and add other behaviors too like Continuations, etc. The key is to use closures and anonymous delegates. Should work in .NET 2.0.

**EDIT** - Here is how you would use it:

```
    public static string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World!"; 
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = BeginTask(HelloWorld); // non-blocking call

        string result = task(); // block and wait

    }
```

Comment: For anyone walking through the code, note BeginInvoke as used above starts HelloWorld on [a new thread from the managed thread pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556634/does-funct-begininvoke-use-the-threadpool).

Answer (score 6):

You will have to use `System.Threading.Thread` class, you can get the `Task` class for .net 3.5 but not for .net 2.

Sorry

Comment: I was under the impression that the Task class comes with .NET 4. How could I use it under 3.5?

Comment: The [Rx](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=179929) team backported `Task` and other low-level abstractions (but not the entire TPL) to .NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: @Christial Schwarz, ^^ as Stephen said, it was backported.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach you can consider is rather than having an asynchronous task thread running (which as you discovered is not really supported in .net 2.0) you can put the asynchronous task in a separate process. This process would be built using later versions of .net, and so can work asynchronously using .net framework's Task.

This is the kind of code to include in the .net framework 2.0 application.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        private Boolean DoMyTaskAsynchronously( )
        { 
            Boolean                         Boolean_Result = false;

            String                          String_ApplicationDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Trim( );
            if( !( String.IsNullOrEmpty( String_Directory)))
            { 
                String_Directory = String_Directory.Replace( "/", ( String)( ( System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).ToString( )));
                if( !( String_Directory.EndsWith( ( String)( ( System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).ToString( )))))
                {
                    String_Directory += System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
                }

                String                      String_ExecutableFileName = "MyAsynchronousApplication.exe";

                String                      String_Argument = "MyArgument";

                Process                     process = new Process( );
                process.StartInfo.FileName = String_ApplicationDirectory + String_ExecutableFileName;
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + String_Argument + "\"";
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.Start( );
                String                      String_Output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd( ).ToUpper( );
                process.WaitForExit( );

                Boolean_Result = ! String.IsNullOrEmpty( String_Output);

            }//if( !( String.IsNullOrEmpty( String_Directory)))

            return Boolean_Result;

        }//private Boolean DoMyTaskAsynchronously( )

    }//public class MyClass

}//namespace MyNameSpace
```

Then you can create application MyAsynchronousApplication.exe as a separate project, and use whatever .net version you would like.
Then you place the executable in the same directory as the original .net 2.0 app. In this example, MyAsynchronousApplication.exe takes a single string argument and reverses its character order in a second thread (which is time-limited to complete in 1 second or less).
An example of its code would be

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyAsynchronousApplicationNameSpace
{
    class MyAsynchronousApplicationClass
    {
        static void Main( String[] f_a_String_Arguments)
        {
            String                                      String_ThisProgramName = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.ToLower( );
            String                                      String_CallingProgramName = Environment.CommandLine.ToLower( );
            Boolean                                     Boolean_CalledFromCommandLine = String_CallingProgramName.IndexOf( String_ThisProgramName) == 0;

            if( !( Boolean_CalledFromCommandLine))
            {
                String                                  String_Argument = f_a_String_Arguments[ 0];
                if( !( String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( String_Argument)))
                { 
                    String                              String_ReversedArgument = FlipTheOrderOfTheArgumentCharactersAsynchronously( String_Argument);
                    if( !( String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( String_ReversedArgument)))
                    { 
                        Console.WriteLine( String_ReversedArgument); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine( "MyAsynchronousApplication.exe failure"); 
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( "No argument supplied to MyAsynchronousApplication.exe"); 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "The executable file MyAsynchronousApplication.exe can not be invoked from the command line.");
            }

        }//static void Main( String[] f_a_String_Arguments)

        private static String FlipTheOrderOfTheArgumentCharactersAsynchronously( String f_r_String)
        { 
            String                              String_Result = "";
            Task<String>                        task = new Task<String>( ( ) => { return ReverseCharacterOrder( f_r_String);});
            Int32                               Int32_WaitTime = 1000;
            task.Start( );

            if( task.Wait( Int32_WaitTime))
            {
                String_Result = task.Result;
            }
            return String_Result;

        }//private Boolean FlipTheOrderOfTheArgumentCharactersAsynchronously( ref String f_r_String)

        public static String ReverseCharacterOrder( String f_String)
        {
            char[] a_char = f_String.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse( a_char);
            return new String( a_char);

        }//public static String ReverseCharacterOrder( String f_String)

    }//class MyAsynchronousApplicationClass

}//namespace MyAsynchronousApplicationNameSpace
```