# Equivalent Task in .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, .net-2.0

I know .NET 2.0 it's probably really old now.
But I have the code that I want to compile under .NET 2.0. Unfortunately, the source uses .NET 4.0 `System.Threading.Tasks`

Here the code:

```
int count = GetCount();

Task[] tasks = new Task[count];

for (int p = 0; p < count; p++)
{
     int current = p;
     tasks[p] = Task.Run(() =>
     {
         // Do something here
     });
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

I'm not expert in threading
can someone reproduce same behavior in .NET 2.0 along with clear explanation?

Comment: This answer can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550933/what-should-i-do-to-use-taskt-in-net-2-0

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however that answer only equivalent as single `Task` instance(?) the codes that i provided seems uses multiple `Task` instances, I'm not really sure tho what `Task.WaitAll(tasks);` do..

Comment: `Tasks.WaitAll` is like a `Thread.Join` on every Thread object in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void Start(){
    int count = GetCount();

    //create an array of Thread objects for later access
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[count];

    for (int p = 0; p < count; p++)
    {
         //Create a new Thread
         threads[p] = new Thread(DoSomething);  //.Net 2.0 doesn't have support for lambda expressions, so use a method instead
         //Start the Thread
         threads[p].Start();
    }

    //Wait for all threads to finish execution
    foreach(var t in threads){
        t.Join(); //Thread.Join blocks until the Thread finished executing
    }
}

//this method will be executed by the threads
public void DoSomething(){

}
```

Comment: this is working, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be to use a BackgroundWorker and wrap it in a helper class.
This way you could also specify additional completion events.

```
public delegate void Action();

public class TaskRunner
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    private bool _complete;
    private int _counter;

    public void AddTask(Action action)
    {
        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (sender, args) => action();
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
            try
            {
                Monitor.Enter(_lock);
                if (--_counter == 0)
                {
                    Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_lock);
            }
        };

        try
        {
            Monitor.Enter(_lock);
            if (_complete)
            {
                throw new Exception("task runner is complete");
            }

            _counter++;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_lock);
        }
    }

    public void Wait()
    {
        while (!_complete)
        {
            try
            {
                Monitor.Enter(_lock);

                if (_counter == 0)
                {
                    _complete = true;
                    return;
                }

                Monitor.Wait(_lock);
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_lock);
            }
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task = new TaskRunner();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        task.AddTask(() => 
        { 
            //Do something
        });
    }

    task.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: haven't try this one, but interesting. btw what namespace i need to add in using directive to use `BackgroundWorker`? also I wonder why throw exception when it's complete? can you please add comments so i can understand more clearly about your codes. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The exception was because I didnt want you to wait on completed tasks, but you could easily ignore that.  BackgroundWorker can be found at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker