# What is the equivalent task in .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I know .NET 2.0 is really old now, but I have code that I want to compile under .NET 2.0. Unfortunately, the source uses .NET 4.0 System.Threading.Tasks

Here is the code:

```
 public override string Encode(byte[] data)
 {
     if (data == null || data.Length == 0)
         return "";

     int mainBitsLength = (data.Length * 8 / BlockBitsCount) * BlockBitsCount;
     int tailBitsLength = data.Length * 8 - mainBitsLength;
     int totalBitsLength = mainBitsLength + tailBitsLength;
     int mainCharsCount = mainBitsLength * BlockCharsCount / BlockBitsCount;
     int tailCharsCount = (tailBitsLength * BlockCharsCount + BlockBitsCount - 1) / BlockBitsCount;
     int totalCharsCount = mainCharsCount + tailCharsCount;
     int iterationCount = mainCharsCount / BlockCharsCount;

     var result = new char[totalCharsCount];

     if (!Parallel)
         EncodeBlock(data, result, 0, iterationCount);
     else {
         int processorCount = Math.Min(iterationCount, Environment.ProcessorCount);
         System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, processorCount, i =>
            {
                int beginInd = i * iterationCount / processorCount;
                int endInd = (i + 1) * iterationCount / processorCount;
                EncodeBlock(data, result, beginInd, endInd);
            });
     }

     if (tailBitsLength != 0)
     {
         ulong bits = GetBits64(data, mainBitsLength, tailBitsLength);
         BitsToChars(result, mainCharsCount, tailCharsCount, bits);
     }

     return new string(result);
 }
```

I'm not an expert in threading. Can someone reproduce same behavior in .NET 2.0 along with clear explanation?

Comment: Use `System.Threading.Thread` and start the treads manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent Task in .NET 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087518/equivalent-task-in-net-2-0)

Comment: Jusrt set `Parallel` to false. Remove nocompiling code.