# Receive packet from the server asynchronously?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, networking

I have a client that is connected to a server successfully. I use the Socket.Receive() method to receive data from the server. However, it is a blocking method. I use Socket.BeginReceive() to receive packets on server side from connected clients asynchronously, is it the same for the client side of I want to receive packets from the server asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, why would it not? Really unsure what else to say.

Consider using `await` instead of the (almost) obsolete APM pattern. It's the same thing in a more convenient form.

Comment: I can't as I am using unity and I'm stuck with.NET 2.0

Comment: Ok I'm going to use the the code in the answer in this question-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550933/what-should-i-do-to-use-taskt-in-net-2-0 in order to make asynchronous operations in .NET 2.0