# TPL-like library for .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, parallels

After discovering the Parallels library in .NET 4.0, I'd like to have something similar in my .NET 2.0 application.

Are there any parallel programming helper libraries for .NET 2.0, that simplify common tasks?

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500614/is-it-possible-to-use-the-task-parallel-library-tpl-in-c-sharp-2-0

Comment: Why exactly do you want to stay on .Net 2.0? You really can't upgrade?

Comment: I'd like to stay on .NET 2.0 because everything else I need is available in .NET 2.0 with minor add-ons (System.Linq via LinqBridge, for example). It simplifies the deployment, since most people will have 2.0 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Threadpool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) would be a nomination in .NET 2.0 which is kind of similar with TPL.

> Provides a pool of threads that can be used to execute tasks, post work items, process asynchronous I/O, wait on behalf of other threads, and process timers.

[`TPL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) actually uses `Threadpool` under the hood:

> TPL handles the partitioning of the work, the scheduling of threads on the ThreadPool, cancellation support, state management, and other low-level details.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [`BackgroundWorker` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) which has been available from .NET Framework 2.0+. There is a lot of information available on how to use this class both on this site and on MSDN.

You can also look at the [`Thread` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx), which has been available from .NET Framework 1.1+. There is also a wealth of information on this class. One resource I particularly like is [J. Albahari's page on threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). This should provide a great starting point for you to get started with these features.

I hope this helps.