# Converting .NET 4 Threading to .NET 2

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am using someone else's .NET 4 open source smoothed particle hydrodynamics code and I'm trying to convert it for a Unity project which you can only count on to be up to .NET 2 standards. Unfortunately the code uses the Parallels class (which is awesome!) but he used one of the more obscure overloads. Can anyone see a good way to achieve the same thing in .NET 2 without a huge performance hit?

```
    Parallel.For(
        0,
        _numActiveParticles,
        () => new Vector2[MAX_PARTICLES],
        (i, state, accumulatedDelta) => calculateForce(_activeParticles[i], accumulatedDelta),
        (accumulatedDelta) =>
        {
            lock (_calculateForcesLock)
            {
                for (int i = _numActiveParticles - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    int index = _activeParticles[i];
                    _delta[index] += accumulatedDelta[index] / MULTIPLIER;
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

I *think* this is what the code does (non threaded):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < _numActiveParticles; i++)
    {
        Vector2[] temp = new Vector2[MAX_PARTICLES];
        temp = calculateForce(_activeParticles[i], temp);


        for (int k = _numActiveParticles - 1; k >= 0; k--)
        {
            int index = _activeParticles[k];
            _delta[index] += temp[index] / MULTIPLIER;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/q/12386686/809009

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Thanks that's helpful but I also am not 100% sure what the Parallels version is doing so I want to make sure I translate it correctly.

Comment: I don't think your understanding is right. You're not even using 'temp' variable anywhere. Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963547.aspx

Comment: I think unity is almost 3.5 although it says 2.0. Here is a relevant link http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/472726/what-net-version-is-unity-41-using.html

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa That was a typo, the variable I had named "bill" was actually supposed to be "temp" (changed in original post now).

Thanks for the link I will take a look

Comment: What's the point in using `Parallel.For` if you're going to `lock` over the entirety of the body?  You may as well just use a regular `for`.  It'll perform way better as it won't have all of that unnecessary synchronization/threading overhead.

Comment: @Servy not sure, I didn't write the original code and it wasn't commented. Regardless, it sounds like you understand that overload of Parallel.For() is doing. Can you explain it?

Comment: @servy the lock is not around the (inner) loop body, but around the "localFinally". Thus, in general the parallelism is still better then in a plain for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your second code isn't correct. I think the correct code is like this:

```
var accumulatedDelta= new Vector2[MAX_PARTICLES];

for(int i = 0; i < _numActiveParticles; ++i)
{
    accumulatedDelta = calculateForce(_activeParticles[i], accumulatedDelta);
}

for (int i = _numActiveParticles - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    int index = _activeParticles[i];
    _delta[index] += accumulatedDelta[index] / MULTIPLIER;
}
```

I don't know what `.net2` has and what doesn't. But you can simulate `Parallel.For` yourself.

explanation of this overload of `Parallel.For` is this:

First parameter: start index of loop

Second parameter: end index of loop

Third parameter: a delegate that will create task local data. for each every thread that `Parallel.For` use (a task) this delegate will be called and return `localInit` data.

Fourth parameter: a delegate that act as body of `for`. In first execution of body delegate, this delegate will retrieve data that is created by previuse delegate (`localInit`). in every subsequent loop, body delegate can change `localInit` and then return that to next body execution. In last execution of body delegate, `localInit` data will be passed to last delegate.

Last parameter: another delegate that will be called per each task, when task has finished it's work. `localInit` will be passed to this delegate. Because this delegate can be called concurrency by multiple tasks, you must protect your shared data.

**Edit:**

A version of `ParallelFor` can be like this:

```
public static void ParallerFor<TLocal>(int startIndex, int endIndex, Func<TLocal> initData, Func<int, TLocal, TLocal> body, Action<TLocal> finalizer)
    {
        int numThreads = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        int chunkOffset = ((endIndex - startIndex) / numThreads) + 1;

        Task[] tasks = new Task[numThreads];

        Enumerable.Range(0, numThreads).ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                int start = x * chunkOffset;
                int end = ((x + 1) * chunkOffset);
                end = end > endIndex ? endIndex : end;

                tasks[x] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    TLocal init = initData();

                    for(int i = start; i < end; ++i)
                    {
                        init = body(i, init);
                    }

                    finalizer(init);
                });
            });

        Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
    }
```

Comment: Using the Task class to reimplement Parallel.For is kind of mood. If you have one, you also have the other (both are .net 4 and up).

Comment: @Christian.K Thank for your mention. I don't know what kind of parallel helpers `.net 2` has, but replacing `task` with manual `thread` starting is a straightforward work.

Comment: You can check msdn. It will tell you. Note that a task is not the same as a thread (at least use the thread pool and not a plain thread). Generally, reimplementing TPL functionality is non trivial to get correct and efficient. Lots of material about that on the internet.