# Running a .NET 4.5 program on XP with .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-xp, .net-4.5

We have a Windows Service written in C# 5.0 for .NET 4.5. My code is using some of the newer language features (`async` and `await`) and framework features (`Task.Run`, `Task.Delay`, `IProgress`, `CancellationToken`, etc).

Our product works fine on Windows **7** and **8** when .NET 4.5 is installed. Our problem is, we now need this to run on an **XP** machine. Even if .NET 4.5 [could be installed on Windows XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8z6watww.aspx), there's not enough space for it on this machine anyway.

Is there any way I can get a .NET 4.5 application to run on this machine? I've looked into compiling the program to native code using either [Mono AOT Compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/AOT) or [NGen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but I haven't had any luck - I don't think either of them actually achieve what I'm trying to do.

Failing that - we've thought of creating a bootable preinstalled flash drive that runs a simple version of Windows (like WinPE?) with our application installed, but this is out of my depth and I wouldn't really know where to start. Is this a good idea? How could I approach this?

Another option we've had is to try and install .NET 4.0 and use the [Async Targeting Pack](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack/).

Or does anyone have any other ideas? Is there any way I can build/compile/run my .NET 4.5 application (that makes use of .NET 4.5 features) on an XP machine running .NET 2.0?

Comment: It would be easier to re-factor your code than to get it run under XP. XP is simply missing too many core DLL changes to run 4.5.

Comment: I don't think it will. I heavily rely on the Task based async features. Refactoring to exclude that would take a **lot** of time and effort in some places!

Comment: Where does that "has to run on an XP machine" demand come from? I'm afraid you have to disappoint your customer. Where to draw the line?

Comment: It's a kiosk provided to us by a 3rd party. The kiosk is contains a small XP machine connected to some hardware which we use in our software.

Comment: @downvoters - are they both because the question is too specific? I can't imagine for one minute that I'm the first person to try this, and I certainly don't think I'll be the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AsyncBridge](https://github.com/OmerMor/AsyncBridge) is like the MS Async Targeting Pack, but also available for .NET 3.5.

However, it won't work with .NET 2.0; as the Task Parallel Library (which defines `Task<T>`) is [only available for .NET 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500614/is-it-possible-to-use-the-task-parallel-library-tpl-in-c-sharp-2-0?lq=1) (and built into .NET 4.0).

As for Mono, to create a standalone application that includes the relevant portions of the framework, you need to create a [bundle](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime#Bundles), but I'm not sure if those are supported on Windows. `mono --aot` and `ngen` just precompile an application for faster startup on the local machine, they don't remove the need for the framework to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one XP machine, upgrade it to Windows 7. Windows 7 includes an XP virtual machine which can run older programs side-by-side with Windows 7 programs (including .NET 4.5 applications).

Otherwise, you'll have to make code changes. The best approach is probably to target .NET 4.0 with [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/).